Google authentication with supabase/React working on localhost but not on production on Vercel
I know this question has already popped up on internet, but I tried all proposed solutions and none worked.
I have some simple authentication with a google token which works fine on localhost (the rest is "simple" React).
When deployed on Vercel, I get the error "This site can't be reached" if I authenticate with Google credentials.
Now I noticed in the bar of the browser, it trying to access : "http://localhost:5173/#access_token=..." maybe something went wrong in the compiling of the react code?
I also tried adding to the OAuth 2.0-Client-IDs API in Google Cloud, the JS-source 'https://my-projects.vercel.app" and in the allowed URIs field "https://myproject.vercel.app//api/auth/callback" but nothing changed.
What am I doing wrong?

can you check the redirectTo in your code. It seems that you do not redirect to url that is in production
